# Strange behavior changing tomcat 7 port

Tags: spring

I'm developing a SOA Spring based webapp which expose the business method throught JAX-WS web services:

When start Tomcat 7 on port 8080 all run as expected. 
If I switch port from 8080 to 8081 (or any other http port) I have a NULL POINTER EXCPETION on a Spring Bean annotated with @Autowired:

```
@Component
@Webservice
public class myappWS
{
@Autowired
private IUserServices userServices;

.....
.....

}


@Service
public class UserServices implements IUserServices{

.....
..... 
.....
}
```

Some suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you forgot to change port for the baseAddress property in your context file.
See this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#remoting-web-services-jaxws-export-standalone)

Comment: Hi Ravi,thank you for interesting answer!

I'm using

without specifying base address.

Reading 'SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter' Spring Documentation I noticed 'base address' is 'http://localhost:8080' by default.

So,tomcat server is listening on 8081,but SimpleJaxWsServiceExporter by deafult listen on 8080. Maybe the problem is in this discrepancy.

I'll test it as soon as possible to post the result.

Thank you